# Services on Windows Mobile 7

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to create a service using XNA/Windows Mobile 7? Similar to how you can in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really possible in 7.0, but if you're using (or targetting) 7.1 (Mango), then you can look into using [Background Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.backgroundagent%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). The link explains the base class, but you can use ScheduledTaskAgent, AudioPlayerAgent and AudioStreamingAgent depending on your need. There's a great introductory tutorial [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2011/07/11/background-agents-part-1-of-3.aspx) and sample codes on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). There's an XNA specific example in this [MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205609%28v=xnagamestudio.41%29.aspx).

The reason `Background Agents` are used is so that different apps can be monitored to ensure one app isn't hogging all the resources. This means that the battery life is more optimised and there's better resource management.

If you mean to use `Services` such that others apps can communicate with your service, this isn't really possible. Each app is sandboxed for security reasons and, at the moment, this means that they can't communicate with other third party apps directly.

Comment: Actually, what I am trying to do is port an application I have on Android over to Windows Mobile 7. What my application does is it subscribes to the [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) intent and whenever a text message comes through the phone, my program acts as a replacement notifier and flashes a light on the Android device.

Comment: There aren't currently any APIs that would allow you to do that. Third party apps can't subscribe to a 'text received' event so your app doesn't have a way of detecting that. Even if it did, it would probably act as an addition to the default notification method instead of replacing it. Slightly unrelated, but if that app was possible (and is not a game), you'd probably want to use the Silverlight framework and not XNA.

Comment: Alright then, so much for my Windows port :) Thanks for the help